# How to compare a numpy array with a scalar?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This question may seem very basic but it's generating a big mess.

I try to compare a `numpy.array` with a scalar as:

```
a=numpy.array([0.,1.,2.,-1.,-4.])
if a.any()>0.:
    print 'a:',a
```

As expected we get:

```
a: [ 0.  1.  2. -1. -4.]
```

Now if I do the same to find negative values

```
a=numpy.array([0.,1.,2.,-1.,-4.])
if a.any()<0.:
    print 'a:',a
```

I don't get anything which means that all values are greater than 0.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by comparing an array to a scalar?

Comment: `a` is the array and `0.` is the scalar or floating point number

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because of that `a.any` returns True (It returns true if one of your elements meets the condition and False otherwise). And since True and 1 are the same objects in Python (True==1), your condition is interpreted as `1<0` by Python, which is False!

```
>>> True<0
False
>>> a.any()<0.
False
```

And instead of that you need  `(a<0).any()`

```
>>> (a<0).any()
True
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what `a.any()` does:

> Returns True if any of the elements of `a` evaluate to True.

You are comparing `True` to `0` in both samples.

```
>>> print a.any()
True
>>> print True < 0.
False
```

To get the negative values in `a` use `a[a < 0.]`:

```
>>> print a[a < 0.]
[-1., -4.]
```

If in doubt, use the built-in `help`.

Comment: @ilciavo It s a function call that returns a boolean. If there is any casting, it would be casting the individual elements of the array to boolean.

Comment: That's what I meant, it casts the values of the array to boolean, and it checks if one of any of these boolean values is True

Answer (score -2):

The method .any() from nd.array is to check if the array exist. Then you can try this:

```
import numpy
a=numpy.array([0.,1.,2.,-1.,-4.])
if a.any()>0.:
    print ('a:',a)

print ('After the first if')

if a[a<0].any()<0.: # This don't work
    print ('a:',a)

print ('After the second if')

if a[a<0].any(): # This is working
    print ('a:',a)

# more tests
print('This is True if a exist', a.any())
print('This is True if exist list with positive elements of a',a[a>0].any())
c = numpy.array([0.,1.,2.])
b = numpy.array([])
print ("The array don't exist ", b.any())
print("The array of elements negative of c don't exist ", c[c<0].any())
```

Comment: Even though you could use `any` to check if an array exists, the main use of `any` is completely different. You may want to read the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html)